# Websockets control user access

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, websocket, ratchet

I am currently using Websockets within my php project [Ratchet, Symfony]. When a user gets logged in, he automatically gets connected to a channel within the websocket connection. I am able to push messages to the channel and to receive + display them on the client. So managing access to the websocket when connecting to it after login is no problem. Assuming we have the following case, I get a problem when it comes to authentication:

1. User is logged in and has access to a channel
2. User logs out on another tab or clears its cache
3. Until the user reloads his page, he still gets the messasges of the websocket channel.

I checked that the user , when using websockets and not ajax, is still logged in on the websocket side symfony session. When I check the same using an ajax demo -request, the user is not logged in anymore. This is the main problem, the websocket session is not synchronized with the symfony session well, because in the symfony session, the user is logged out but on the Websocket , he is still logged in.

Initially, I tried the following to avoid the described scenario above:

1. When a user gets a new message through the websocket channel, I first check by using a remote call procedure if the user is still logged in by sending a flag true or false from server (Thats where the problem with the unsynchronized session occurs)
2. When the flag is false, I unsubscribe the user from the channel
3. When the flag is true, I process the callback of the websocket channel.

In general, I think this approach would be fine (?) , but the problem I see is the unsychronized session. How to synchronize it or force the websocket channel to check for the cookie / send it again when a push reaches it? How do you handle this kind of situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I personnaly solved this issue.
I saved each connectionId I have while it was open in my database.

Then I checked which connections should receive for what channel and only sent a message to those that should receive it.

Afterwards once your problem comes up: a user logs out, then I remove the user from the database with open connections and each new message to those channels will not be sent to the user anymore.

EDIT:
To solve the problem proposed here: a user refreshes his/her cache/cookies, but the connection is still open, how can I be ensured that the connection is still safe?

Answer: If a user refreshes his/her cache the socketconnection would stay in existance, although the user would close it once the browser is refreshed/redirected. The safety problem here is inexistant since the user was connected in a right way in the beginning of the session, and then cleared their cache, so that they are logged out.

If the user has bad intentions, then the connection should have never been established in the first place.

Comment: then the user will lose his session although you will still have the session on the server. So you could resend the session to the user or make a new one once the user logs in again and save that over the previous connectionId.
In what way are you currently storing the session in a cookie?

Comment: Im storing by using PdoSessionHandler. In my opinion, your solution does not handle the case when the user has its browser opened, clears his cache / cookies . Because he will still get messages through the websocket until he reloads the page? The user just looses its session on the client site, but on websocket side, he is still authenticated.

Comment: I thought of sending the session id in the remote procedure call by reading the cookie's session id, and then check if the value and the stored session id within websocket server match. If not, he is not authenticated anymore (at least at who he claimed to be). But this is not possible, because I cannot read a secure cookie from within the browser..

Comment: So you can not read a sessionId/connectionId from a cookie compare it to the websocket session that is open and only use the received data if those are the same?

Comment: Since then when a user clears his cache/cookies those won't be the same or he was messing with cookies and they aren't the same, so that he will be redirected to a login/refresed

Comment: You misunderstand the question. When connecting to a websocket server, you share the session / cookie ONCE with it. So you won't get updates on the websocket side session / cookie until you reconnect to the websocket server. The problem is, that I am not able to send the CLIENT side cookies to the websocket server. So I cannot compare a cookie that I cannot send.

Comment: No you are wrong mitchken, when using websockets, the websocket server is not able to detect a session change / cookie change until you reconnect to a channel. Try my points 1-3 out ;)

Comment: oh that I have not used myself yet, I am sorry for misunderstanding you

Comment: You haven't used websockets yet? Because thats what always happens when using websockets. Cookie is only send once when connecting --

Comment: I have used websockets before often, but I never sent a cookie through my websocket before since I didn't see the need for it.

Comment: Ok, so I think i understand what you wanted to say: As the session cookie does not exist anymore, the session cannot be hijacked anymore either and so it's not important that the user still gets messages when the browser is still opened?

Comment: yes that is my point, since no one will be able to use it anymore or be able to somehow hijack his/her connection. Except from the browser itself of course but that user already had access so there is no point for that user to 'hack' his already allowed connection

Comment: no problem, should I sum it up in my original post?

Comment: Yes, I will then accept your answer :). I searched a lot and I've seen that a lot of other people had this problem without getting a reliable answer.